# load a variable in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, variables, matlab-load

I want to load variables in a loop with different imagenames.

```
for i=1:length(imagefile) 
      name=imagefile{i}; 
% name=image01% load name  
end
```

it looks variable (name) and not (image01), how should I do it
regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what your variable is. An array of strings?

```
imaefgile = ["image01", "image02"]
for i=1:length(imaefgile)
    load(imaefgile(i))
end
```

P.S. you may also need something like:

```
load(strcat("Folder/", imaefgile(i), ".mat"))
```

to concatenate the filename appropriately.